Animated Kids TV show about hunting monsters aired around 2000-2005?
There was this TV show that aired from like 2000-2005. It was about three kids (two girls and a guy )who hunted monsters. 
There was this girl who was the leader, she was really pale, had red short hair,freckles an, glasses and a coat where she had all sorts of utensils and gadgets.
Then the was the other girl, I think she had a pink shirt, brown skin  and she had psychic powers, she could read minds and also move things with it. 
Finally there was the guy, he had blonde hair, blue eyes and he could turn into any object he wanted.
I remember perfectly this one episode where they had to kill this green snake. The animation of the show was sort of similar to Coraline.
